# Amplifying signal with Darlington not working

Tags: signal-processing, darlington, flow-sensor, voltage-amplification

I'm relatively new to electronics and this is not my usual field of work.

For a bigger project I need to read a flow sensor's (Biotech FCH-C-PA-N) output. The output needs to be processed by an Arduino or Raspberry. The problem I have: The flow sensor's output (a square wave with varying frequency) has a Voltage between 0mV-220mV where the ~220mV represents the HIGH state.

How do I amplify the 220mV to 3.3V (RaspberryPi) or 5V (Arduino)?

I thought about using a darlington-circuit. But even with three Transistors (BC547) somehow I can't read a HIGH state at the microcontrollers input. The darlington circuit doesn't open.

[image]

**edit: Problem solved**

As stated by WhatRoughBeast this sensor works as intended without trying to amplify the signal (which was done wrong by me anyway due to a misunderstanding of the amplifying effect of transistors). It turned out that the used sensor was "FCH-C-PA" and not "FCH-C-PA-N" (I got the wrong manual by the seller). This one uses NPN open collector sinking, so WhatRoughBeast's answer is correct.

The reason why I couldn't get the correct signals at first (after plugging in the pull-up resistor) was a short-circuit at the electrical connection which was encased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you have ignored the part of the data sheet which states that the sensor output is "open collector NPN". Disconnect the Darlington, and connect a 10k resistor from the sensor output to +5. The fact that you're seeing 220 mV is just an artifact of leakage.

With a 10k to +5, you'll see 0 - 5 volts pulses, and you can tie these directly to your Arduino.

And, just to make things clear, you must also get rid of your pulldown resistor.

Comment: @DeMo BioTech datasheets claim that Durchflussmesser FCH-CE-PA has open collector NPN sink output, Durchflussmesser FCH-CE-PA-N has PNP output with internal 2.2kOhm pull-up resistor. There's error somewhere. https://www.btflowmeter.com/fileadmin/PDF/Flowmeter/97478988-FCH-CE-PA.pdf and the other  http://www.produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/500000-524999/503591-da-01-ml-DURCHFLUSSMESSER_FCH_C_PA_de_en.pdf

Comment: Well, OK, no problem. If a 10k to +5 doesn't do anything (other than pull the output up to +5), try a 10k to ground. If you've got a PNP output, that will work. Either way, there is no sense in trying to amplify a signal which ought to be adequate without amplification.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I tried to modify the circuit like you described it but sadly I still don't get the desired signal. All the arduino sees is a LOW signal. This is what my setup looks like now: [Link to image](https://screenshotscdn.firefoxusercontent.com/images/67263fe1-2ce3-4230-8f0f-c385e2bf01f4.png).


The other suggested method does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

1. A darlington is pointless here.  For your purpose, there is nothing useful a darlington does that a single BJT couldn't do.

   You are using the transistor in *emitter follower* mode.  That provides current gain but no voltage gain.

   Since the transistor is used as emitter follower, the output is lower than the input by the B-E drop.  That B-E drop is larger than your signal, so you never get any output.  Note that a darlington actually makes this worse since it has two B-E drops.  However, the B-E drop of a single transistor would still be too big anyway.

While it is possible to amplify this signal by using a few transistors, it is easier to use a opamp.  Get a opamp that is *rail to rail* for both the input and the output.  Something like a MCP606 would probably do.  I'm assuming the output of this "flow sensor" has a bandwidth well below the 150 kHz or so the MCP606 can do.  Wire the opam in classic positive gain configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much. Why is it not possible to just use a single BJT as a switch in this scenario? Wouldn't a voltage applied to the base bring the resistance between the collector end emitter down to nearly 0?